# Wait for .onload and check resolution for multiple images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

User has a button where he can add multiple images. Now, I need to check every image resolution, and if all resolutions are above 800x600, then I need to upload images, otherwise, throw an error.

This need to look something like this:

```
prepareFilesList(files) {
  if (!this.verifyFilesResolution(files)) {
    this.selectedFiles = files; 
    this.uploadFiles();
  } else {
    return this.toastr.error('Image must be at least 800x600 .');
  }
 }

 verifyFilesResolution(files): boolean {
    let err = false;

    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let img = new Image();
  
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        img.onload = function () {

          if (img.width <= 800 || img.height <= 600) {
            err = true;
          }

        };
      }
    }

    return err;
  }
```

But, in this case, it doesn't work, because it doesn't wait for `.onload` and in all cases it throw an error. Somehow I need to wait for `.onload` and to loop trough all files or al least one where resolution isn't above 800x600.

How I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: I doubt onload will ever trigger if you do not attach the image to the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onload` function is called back asynchronously, so all your loop does as your code is written now is set up the callbacks, it won't ever wait for them to be done. You need something more like this (this is a general idea -- I haven't tested it):

```
prepareFilesList(files) {
  this.verifyFilesResolution(files, success => {
    if (success) {
      this.selectedFiles = files; 
      this.uploadFiles();
    } else {
      return this.toastr.error('Image must be at least 800x600 .');
    }
  });
}

 verifyFilesResolution(files, callback): boolean {
    let err = false;
    let imagesLoaded = 0;

    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let img = new Image();
  
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        img.onload = function () {
          if (img.width <= 800 || img.height <= 600) {
            err = true;
          }

          if (++imagesLoaded === files.length) {
            callback(!err);
          }
        };
      }
    }

    return err;
  }
```

Note: You should look into `onerror` and deal with failed image loads too.

Comment: Yes, this is working for me, I just need to call an arrow callback function, the rest is fine. Thank you.

Comment: My first impulse was to use an arrow function, but I changed to an old-fashioned function just to stick with the existing code style you had. I didn't take enough notice of your use of `this` to realize an arrow function was necessary.